# How to use doxygen preprocessor on this example fortran code?

Tags: fortran, preprocessor, doxygen

In a fortran source file named lib_angles.f90, I have the following function declaration,

```
#ifdef NDEBUG  
pure function la_get_quadrant(A)  
#else  
function la_get_quadrant(A)  
#endif
```

I use the following settings in the config file,

```
ENABLE_PREPROCESSING   = YES
MACRO_EXPANSION        = NO
PREDEFINED             = NDEBUG
```

Running the latest version of doxygen (1.8.5) yields the following output,

```
(...)
Reading /home/pmginacio/bin/doc/test/lib_angles.f90...  
Parsing file /home/pmginacio/bin/doc/test/lib_angles.f90...  
********************************************************************  
Error in file /home/pmginacio/bin/doc/test/lib_angles.f90 line: 38, state: 4  
********************************************************************  
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

The problem seems lie with the preprocessor who is not selecting one of the function declarations. When I comment one of them in the code,

```
#ifdef NDEBUG  
pure function la_get_quadrant(A)  
#else  
!function la_get_quadrant(A)  
#endif
```

doxygen executes normally.

Why? How should one use the preprocessor?

Comment: There's more to the problem than what you've presented here.  A minimal input file based on the content in your question works for me.

Comment: The problem can be reproduced by just adding the statement end function to the example. The problem is the extension of the file. With extension the f90 the #if is just seen as comment as no preprocesing is done, and thus 2 function starts are seen and only 1 function end. Using the extension F90 preprocessing is executed and only one function start is present.

Comment: I've changed the extension of the file and it now works fine. Thanks to both for your feedback.